# Visual Studio 2008 C++ Writing to a dialog during OnInit or at startup

Tags: visual-c++

Ok, If I cannot write on a dialog during oninit by:

---

You can't use the function SSTextOut() in OnInitDialog(). OnInitDialog() is called before your dialog is displayed, so you can't get a valid CDC inside of it (because the dialog hasn't been drawn yet).

From the looks of it, SSTextOut() is meant to be called from an OnPaint() override.

---

Is there any way I can write some text to the 1st dialog screen at startup.  I want to put some info on the dialog screen under program control rather then by static text!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `SSTextOut` is, but during OnInitDialog, the dialog *does* have a valid DC. It hasn't been *displayed* yet, but it does exist, and so do all the controls in the dialog, so putting text into a control (e.g. an Edit control) is perfectly valid, and when the user sees the dialog, the text will be there as soon as the user sees the dialog.

Comment: SSTextOut does not work as you need pDC->SSTextOut which I could not get.             BUT, I put up an Edit Box and used the following code to write into it:         CEdit *Display; Display = reinterpret_cast<CEdit *>(GetDlgItem(IDC_LC_EDITBX));  
Display->SetWindowText("Word Processing"); UpdateData(FALSE);          Now I need to make the edit box so you can't see it so all you see is the text I put up! Thanks

Comment: You can just use `pDC->TextOut(x, y, "Your Text");`. Alternatively, you can set the edit control to have no border (or use a static control, but set its ID to something other than IDC_STATIC, and write to it the same way -- that keeps the user from editing it (even by accident). You don't really need the `reinterpret_cast` and `GetDlgItem` either -- it's much easier to associate a CEdit member variable with the item ahead of time.